# How to transfer USD amount to linked account using Razorpay Route

Tags: javascript, php, api, rest, razorpay

I'm working to integrate the Rayzorpay route payment API and have successfully completed capturing payment and transfer the amount to route linked user account functionality in test mode using INR as default currency.
I have to do same thing using USD or other currency. When I try to change the currency from INR to USD getting following error

Fatal error: Uncaught Razorpay\Api\Errors\BadRequestError: Currency is not supported

For fixing this I created tickect to enable International Payment Support in my Razorpay account.

when I checking this link : https://razorpay.com/docs/international-payments/#supported-products

It says Route not supported this functionality

Can anyone please confirm, Is possible to capture the payment in USD or any other currency and transfer the amount to Rayzorpay route linked account?

Any help would be greatly appreciated